# How to combine two SQLite SELECT statement with two conditions

Tags: objective-c, ios, sqlite, select, limit

Here i want to select questions with two different difficulty from same table. I am using query :

```
readAllQuestions = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT * FROM tbl_questions WHERE difficulty IN(1,3) AND approved = 1"];
```

Its working. Now i want to limit the questions to 100 and it includes 50 questions with difficulty 1 and other 50 with difficulty 3. Using `LIMIT` only give first 100 questions.

How to do this without using two different queries?? Please help..

Comment: Look up `UNION` - `LIMIT` is a view operation so it will need to be included on each of the *independent* sub-queries.

Comment: @pst  I have tried this, but not worked : SELECT * FROM tbl_dn_questions WHERE difficulty = 1 AND approved = 1 LIMIT 50 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM tbl_dn_questions WHERE difficulty = 3 AND approved = 1 LIMIT 50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so with subselects:
(assuming the primary key is called 'id')

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_questions WHERE (id IN (SELECT id FROM tbl_questions WHERE difficulty = 1 LIMIT 0,50) OR id IN (SELECT id FROM tbl_questions WHERE difficulty = 3 LIMIT 0,50)) AND approved = 1
```

Comment: Thank you Cromax. This query retrieved 50 with difficulty 1 and 50 with difficulty 3 but not in the order of id(not first 50 in each case).. How to get it in the order??

Comment: Do you want every difficult block ordered by id or do you want all 100 ordered by id? First: SELECT * FROM tbl_questions WHERE (id IN (SELECT id FROM tbl_questions WHERE difficulty = 1 ORDER BY id LIMIT 0,50) OR id IN (SELECT id FROM tbl_questions WHERE difficulty = 3 ORDER BY id LIMIT 0,50)) AND approved = 1 Second: SELECT * FROM tbl_questions WHERE (id IN (SELECT id FROM tbl_questions WHERE difficulty = 1 LIMIT 0,50) OR id IN (SELECT id FROM tbl_questions WHERE difficulty = 3 LIMIT 0,50)) AND approved = 1 ORDER BY id

Comment: Your answer is perfectly working for two of my four tables in database. But for other two, it give me questions without any order of id. May be problem is not in your query. I will check it. Thank you for your reply...:)